# Multi Step Form Buttons

Tags: multi-step

I have a tricky situation, pretty much I have 3 steps in my form. Also to note I have breadcrumbs up there with an arrow to get back to the table.

Anyways, I have 3 steps and my plan was to have Buttons for Next,Back/Exit. But also since this form is for creating menu in my case I can't just have Next since after Step 2 I can create Menu or go Next to have QR Generator (which is not necessary step). So pretty much at the Step 2 I would have button for Back, Cancel,Next, Save&Exit. UX is good I guess with those buttons but UI I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, step 2 is the last step that is required? the QR step is optional and that is what is planned for step 3? I would have advised against adding the "Save & Exit" button in step 2. I would let the user move to step 3, where I would show a summary of all he has done in the previous steps plus the option to generate the QR. There, in step 3, I would have the "Add" or "Save" button that replaces the "Next" button from the previous steps. It was not mentioned in your description so I'd mention that it is good practice to include in multi-step forms the general layout of the flow ("Step1 > Step 2 > Step 3").